# react - reset child component from parent

Tags: reactjs

I need to reset a child component from parent. I know the best way is to send a props. So I send reset = true as properties. But looks like I need to have a callback function to parent from the child to change that properties to false after reset is done, so if it happens again, the rest works.

I do not want to use refs as it is not the best method, but I do not want to have callbacks too.

What other suggestion you would have?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: unmount and mount again the child

Comment: What is the purpose of this? What is your use case

Comment: I believe it is okay to use refs in such cases, take a look at the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom

Comment: Thanks. I decided not to use reset props. Just send the default value props again to it.